# How do to multiple grep in if statement bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I tried to use this

```
if `$(egrep '(cinta|aduh|siapa)' $inputFile)` ; then
  filter='love'
else `$(egrep '(kok|aku|dan)' $inputFile)` ; then
  filter='jangan'
else `$(egrep '(mari)' $inputFile)`; then
  filter='mari'
else `$(egrep '(kerumah|bebeb)' $inputFile)`; then
  filter='bebeb'
else `$(egrep '*' $inputFile)`; then
  filter='other'
fi
```

but i get result

```
./amosv5: line 175: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./amosv5: line 175: `  then'
```

Why am I getting this error.

i need to make it like this in php

```
if (strpos($inputfile, "cinta") || strpos($inputfile, "aduh") || strpos($inputfile, "siapa") {
$filter = 'love';
} else { $filter = 'other'; } }
```

Comment: Use `http://www.shellcheck.net/` to fix such trivial syntax issues

Comment: What sort of input do you have?  It seems very odd that the filter should be `bebeb` if "kerumah" is in the file, but it changes to `jangan` if "kok" is added to the file.  Is your input file constrained?  (eg, one word only).  If the input is simple, this could probably be done with a nice case statement.

Comment: i am confused to fix it. please help me

Comment: if (strpos($inputfile, "cinta") || strpos($inputfile, "aduh") || strpos($inputfile, "siapa") {
    $filter = 'love';
  }  else {
   $filter = 'other';
  }
}


simple as that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is plain *wrong*!

You can use return code of *most* of the shell utilities directly on the `bash` conditionals. Here in first condition `egrep` with multiple pattern match `cinta|aduh|siapa` will return true if it is able to find *any* of the patterns. Similarly this can be done for the rest of the parts.

```
if egrep 'cinta|aduh|siapa' "$inputFile" ; then
    filter='love'
elif egrep 'kok|aku|dan' "$inputFile" ; then
    filter='jangan'
..
```